# Securing application access to pre authorized individuals only

Tags: php, windows, security, ssl, iis

I am building a PHP application and would like to lock the backend (even login page) to only be accessible to preauthorized people - even further be able to link activities to the authorized individuals.

I am aware that such locking may be done using SSL or a certificate of sort but not sure what it is exactly or how to achieve it. I have seen different companies implement it in ways as mentioned below

- At one company, A user fills in a form with details and the company issues a certificate that the user installs on the browser in order to access the backend
- Another company, A user is given an exe to run each time they want to access the backend.

My PHP application is running on windows server 2016 and I would like to know how to achieve both or either of the above. A resource or specific would be appreciated.

I am not sure if this question is right here or another Stack Exchange
Network, kindly forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Cross posted on security.stackexchange. VTC'd

Comment: @SmokeDispenser mate, seeking help it aint a battle

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

Do not cross post on different networks.

Secondly, the way to do this is to supply client certificates from another web app that are accepted by the app you're developing. Key words for research are: TLS, client certificates, certificate based authentication.